# weird screen glitches in KDE

Tags: lubuntu, kubuntu, kde, 19.04

I've installed KDE on lubuntu 19.04
and i have weird glitches "things appear and disappear randomly"
this is a video showing that glitch
https://youtu.be/hzWpQg9foRY

what I've tried:
changing rendering backend to every single option possible but nothing helped and the same for vsync 
[About System Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDxHB.png)

Versions: KDE plasma 5.16
Ubuntu: 19.04

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this fixed my problem
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1595276#p1595276

and this is what i did
first i created this file

```
sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

then added this in it

```
Section "Device"
Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
Driver      "intel"
#Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
Option      "TearFree"    "true" 
Option      "DRI"    "3" 
EndSection
```